# How to conform to REST url patterns instead of method names

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api

Say I had a few business entities that I want to query from the Db, and do this within a Web API.  Say, Customers and Orders. Each order can have exactly one customer.

Say I wanted to get
-  all the orders for a given customer
-  for a given order, return an object that contains some customer attributes, along with that customers 5 most recent order#'s

https://github.com/Microsoft/api-guidelines/blob/master/Guidelines.md#71-url-structure

Ive tended to use method names like these.

OrdersController:
- GetOrders
- GetordersforCustomer(int CustomerId)
- GetOrderWithCustomerInfo(int CustomerId)

CustomerController
- GetCustomer(int id)
- GetCustomerWithinZipcode

So using API controller methods like this does not follow the REST "guidelines" ive seen elsewhere, correct?  If not, how could I restructure my controllers to accomodate the standard HTTP method names, especially when there are related entities?

For example, I need a call that returns an object that includes attributes from not just an order but the top 5 orders from the customer on the current order. I need a method that gets an order result, but also need a method that gets a different kind of order result - one with some attributes from a customer and/or maybe a few other entities.

example of what im talking about - using only http verbs but with related entities
https://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api#restful
*But how do you deal with relations? If a relation can only exist within another resource, RESTful principles provide useful guidance. Let's look at this with an example. A ticket in Enchant consists of a number of messages. These messages can be logically mapped to the /tickets endpoint as follows:*

```
GET /tickets/12/messages - Retrieves list of messages for ticket #12
GET /tickets/12/messages/5 - Retrieves message #5 for ticket #12
POST /tickets/12/messages - Creates a new message in ticket #12
PUT /tickets/12/messages/5 - Updates message #5 for ticket #12
PATCH /tickets/12/messages/5 - Partially updates message #5 for ticket #12
DELETE /tickets/12/messages/5 - Deletes message #5 for ticket #12
```

Answer (score 0):

Question is broad and also opinion based.

That said, there is no need to restructure the controllers.

Research using attribute routing.

Reference [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing)

Given the linked guidelines an example of potential routes could look like below suggestions.

```
[Route([controller])]
OrdersController:
    //Matches GET orders
    [HttpGet]
    GetOrders()

    //Matches GET customers/1234/orders
    [HttpGet(~/customers/{customerId:int}/orders)]
    GetOrdersForCustomer(int customerId)

    Matches GET orders/1324/customer/5678
    [HttpGet({orderId:int}/customer/{customerId:int})]
    GetOrderWithCustomerInfo(int orderId, int customerId)

[Route([controller])]
CustomersController
    //Matches GET customers
    [HttpGet]
    GetCustomers()

    //Matches GET customers/1234
    [HttpGet("{id:int}")]
    GetCustomer(int id)

    //Matches GET zipcodes/90210/customers
    [HttpGet("~/zipcodes/{zipCode:int}/customers")]
    GetCustomerWithinZipcode(int zipCode)
```

Comment: see update "example of what im talking about".  Im not concerned so much about HOW to route, but how or if I can use strictly http verbs (as per REST) in all cases.  In other words, when is using only the http verbs break down?